# How to find files with certain text in the Terminal

Tags: macos, mac, unix, terminal, search

I'd like to find all files that contain a certain string of text. How would you do that in the Terminal?

Comment: If you want a fast result, use Spotlight, though. Also if you want to find files that don't necessarily store text directly within the file such as PDF or ODF.

Comment: Good advice, but in my case I'm not sure the files are indexed since they are on network drivers. And also they are xml files belonging to a particular program.

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37932/213832 this solution works well

Answer (score 418, accepted):

```
grep -r 'text goes here' path_goes_here
```

Comment: I would suggest a `man grep` to discover all the wonderful options of grep

Comment: This lists every file that exists in the path and adds : `No such file or directory`

I am trying to get just the list of text occurrences. How can we get that list?

Comment: Got it:

`grep -lr "text pattern" ./ -s` ; `grep -lr "text pattern" [PATH OF PARENT] -s`

Comment: But this returns the contents of matching files, not the file details (name, path). @CP3O's suggestion works.

Comment: How to hide "permission denied" results?

Comment: @user517095: Forward  ERRORS/permission denied results to a logfile or /dev/null in STD with: "2", like:
`grep -r 'text goes here' path_goes_here 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 43):

use spotlight

```
mdfind "text goes here"
mdfind -onlyin /home/user/Desktop -live "live update"
```

don't forget to look at:

```
man mdfind
```

Comment: Will this work for files that spotlight doesn't index (i.e. files inside hidden folders, system config files, etc)?

Comment: Grep doesn't seem to parse .xlsx files, but this worked out fine.
Another easy example: mdfind -onlyin . "searchtext"

Answer (score 25):

1. Through Ack

```
brew install ack 
ack "text goes here"
```

2. Through find

```
find . |grep "text goes here"
```

3. Through grep

```
grep -RnslI "text goes here"
```

Comment: "find" would list the filenames, not their content.

Answer (score 5):

You can choose one of the below depending on your taste and needs. Supposing you need to search for files containing text - "async", recursively in current directory, you can do so in one of the ways like below:

**Using grep**
[image]

**Using ack**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ignacio's Answer is great and helped me find the files containing certain text. The only issue I was facing was that when running this command all the files would be listed, including one where the pattern did not show up.

`No such file or directory` This is what I see alongside files that do not contain the pattern.

If instead you add `-s` to the command, as in:
`grep -lr "text pattern" ./ -s` ; `grep -lr "text pattern" [PATH DIRECTORY] -s` is used, it will only show you which files contain the pattern.

Similarly if `grep -nr "text pattern" ./ -s` ; `grep -nr "text pattern" [PATH OF DIRECTORY] -s` command is used it prints the file plus the line number, and occurrence of the pattern.

Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

[Reference: How can I have grep not print out 'No such file or directory' errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426363/how-can-i-have-grep-not-print-out-no-such-file-or-directory-errors)

Comment: Another way to avoid those pesky *No such file* errors, is to pipe stderr to null. `grep ... 2>/dev/null`. This solution works for most programs, since they report error messages on the stderr stream, not stdout. I have used this solution many times with `find`, as it will say *Permission denied* for many files.

Comment: (1) If you’re getting `No such file or directory` messages for files that exist, either you’re doing something wrong, or your system is broken. (2) What does *`[PATH OF PARENT]`* have to do with anything?

Comment: @G-Man I edited the answer to show `[PATH OF DIRECTORY]` just incase someone unfamiliar wanted to know why I had put `./`

Comment: @G-Man I'm using a mac not Ubuntu, not sure how my system would be broken, I've barely done anything on it yet.